# Circular dependency in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I'm trying to build a custom hook that has to alter values before using Formik's `setFieldValue()`.

Here is how to hook looks like:

```
export const useCount = (tab) => {
  const { values, setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();

  const { count} = values;

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleChange = () => {
      if (tab === 0) {
        setFieldValue("count", count);
      } else if (tab === 1) {
        setFieldValue("count", count * 2);
      }
    };

    handleChange();
  }, [count]);
};
```

The issue at hand is that I end up with an infinite loop, due to the fact that I'm changing `count` inside the `useEffect()`. Any clues?

Comment: Why do you call `handleChange` inside the `useEffect`?

Comment: Could you explain what what this `useCount` should be doing?

Comment: I have a Formik form in another component with an input field in it, named `count`. Every time `count` is changed I to modify it before saving it.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `count` on `tab` in your useEffect, to trigger this effect only when `tab` is changed

```
export const useCount = tab => {
  const {values: {count}, setFieldValue} = useFormikContext();

  const handleChange = () => {
     if (tab === 0) {
        setFieldValue("count", count);
     } else if (tab === 1) {
        setFieldValue("count", count * 2);
     }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    handleChange();
  }, [tab]);
};
```